# Httpclient Return BadRequest alsways couldnt understand the issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net5

**Hi I am a Web Api beginner am trying to call one api in another api in asp.net core 3.1. I created two solutions with diffrent port numbers. From httpclient method breakpoint is not going to external api methode.its returning a response as bad request please someone tell what i did wrong here?**

I tried your all httpclient method but i am getting the same error bad request..let me explain what i was trying..

I have 2 solutions here with having diffrent port numbers..

in 1st solution i have a method

```
[HttpPost("api/Product/Check1st")]  
public async Task Check([FromBody] CheckInput input)  
{  
var result = await _productqualityChecker.CheckQualityAsync(input);  
return new JsonResult(result);  
 }
```

I will keep running this solution . The url here ***api/Product/Check1st***" i will trying to call using httpclient in 2nd solution.so this url i am not giving in postman .

In my 2nd solution I have a methode ***[HttpPost("api/ProductQuality/Checkin2nd")]{}***

this 2nd url i will give to postman and getting the input(arguments to call external api) and then it will call the httpclient as shown as below
In postman I issue a request with the following body against

```
   `http://localhost:2000/api/ProductQuality/Checkin2nd`:
```

This is the body/input/argument i am passing in the postman

```
{
"productid": "2274",
"productcorenumber": "1321",
"value": "AE1C1F-0363-D6F-B3D-AE0029A8",
"contacts": [
15998,
1012
],
"ispassed": "0",
"isok": "0",
"isgood": "false"
}
```

and this will come to here(I have one method in my controller)

```
[HttpPost("api/ProductQuality/Checkin2nd")]  
public async Task Check([FromBody] CheckInput input)  
{  
var result = await _Checker.Checkercall(input);  
}
```

in `Checkercall` implementation I am calling another API(as of now calling the same for testing purposes)

```
public async Task Checkercall(CheckInput input)  
{  
QualityCheckResults QualityCheckInputResult = new QualityCheckResults();  
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())  
 {  
 var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input), Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");  
using (var response = await 
httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:2001/api/ProductQuality/Check1st", content))  
//hope i have to give https here  
{  
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
 QualityCheckInputResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(apiResponse);  
 }  
  }  
  return QualityCheckInputResult;  
   }
```

This is what i am trying to do. in httpclient mtd ***CheckInput*** is the class i have created .

***QualityCheckResults QualityCheckInputResult = new QualityCheckResults();*** is the response class.So i can assign to this object only..May be that is the issue? i dont know

Is there anything wrong in my 2 solution call?

Comment: In your first example, change `public async Task Check([FromBody] CheckInput input)` to `public async Task<IActionResult> Check([FromBody] CheckInput input)`

Comment: Instead of `return new JsonResult(result);` do `return Ok(result);`

Comment: change `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(apiResponse);` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QualityCheckInputResult>(apiResponse);`

Comment: still i am getting BAD Request in  Var response....

Comment: What is the value of `apiResponse`? It should contain the error message if this response failed with a BadRequest.

Comment: here in responce i have checked .its showing status code:400 reason:Bad requestusing (var response = await 
httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:2001/api/ProductQuality/Check1st", content))

Comment: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:

{

  Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2021 09:54:45 GMT

  Server: serverA

  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

  Content-Length: 35

}}